# How can I access enum's "overridden" name() method from kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Take for example the [`Regions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/Regions.html) enum from AWS 1.11 java sdk. This class contains a `String getName()` method. When developing with the AWS SDK in Kotlin, this method is provided as

```
Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.name
```

The IntelliJ auto completion popup even says *(from getName())* to let you know that [the compiler treats the getter like a property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters).

The problem becomes apparent when you notice that

```
new AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.getName())
    .build()
```

works in Java, while the equivalent

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.name)
    .build()
```

does not work in Kotlin. Printing the following with Java shows why this is the case:

```
System.out.println(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.getName()); // prints "eu-central-1"
System.out.println(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.name()); // prints "EU_CENTRAL_1"
```

**How do I access a `.getName()` method on a Java enum from Kotlin, as Kotlin prefers the `.name()` method instead?**

Comment: Use region.name to get EU_CENTRAL_1, and use region.getName() to get eu-central-1

Comment: I know. I stated that in my question. The point is, these are the same in Kotlin. Please read the question carefully. - Anyway, it's not about aws, it's about java-kotlin interoperability.

Comment: Well, I just tested creating an enum with a public getName() method in Java, and doing just what I advise in my comment, and it works fine. Have you actually tested it? I **have** read the question carefully, and you never use getName() in the Kotlin code of your question.

Comment: What made you think that `getName()` overrides `name()`?

Comment: It does not override it per-se, that is why I put it in quotes, it overrides in it in the sense, that the kotlin compiler interprets any `getFoo()` method as an implicit `.foo` property. Therefore `name` can resolve to `getName()` if the latter exists. In this case both `name()` and `getName()` exist. I would expect it to resolve to the latter (as IntelliJ suggests) but it resolves to the former.

Comment: See the official documentation for this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: "Therefore name can resolve to getName() if the latter exists. In this case both name() and getName() exist. I would expect it to resolve to the latter (as IntelliJ suggests) but it resolves to the former." `name` here gets inherited from https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/name.html, so IntelliJ has a bug.

Comment: That doc page really should mention that you can't use a Java getter as a property if a method with the name of that property already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested from the comments:

```
// Kotlin
Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.name
```

in Kotlin resolves to

```
// Java
Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.name()
```

in Java, while

```
// Kotlin
Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.getName()
```

can be used to access the function `getName()` of the `Regions` enumeration.

This in turn leads to the question: What are the specific kotlin compiler java method name to property resolution rules?

Comment: I am sorry that I responded in the way I did. I believe your comment is easy to mistake for someone that skimmed the question and thought it was "hurr durr, how do I get eu-central-1 string?" as you only reference the AWS part, but do not mention the fact that .getName() can still be called directly. (I witnessed something like this too often on the internet. Sorry for judging too quickly.)